# I will get better

Tags: grammaire

`je vais aller mieux` or `je deviendrai meilleur` ?

Je vais aller mieux seems to suggest `I am going to...` whereas je deviendrai is `I will get`

Comment: Please add some context to the question. Both translations are actually valid, at least if my english is not too broken:  "I suck at basket ball but I will get better"=>"Je suis nul au basket ball mais je vais devenir meilleur" / "I'm sick now but I will get better" => "Je suis malade mais je vais aller mieux"

Comment: "Je vais devenir" or "je deviendrai" or are both correct? I'm just curious really Laurent, if they are all correct then great or if one is more widely used in everyday spoken French and one is grammatically correct etc. I guess I'm just looking for the common usage. Thanks for your input.

Comment: They're both correct for sure, and I can't tell whether one is more idiomatic than the other. Maybe the form "je vais + infinitive" is a bit more informal than the other as we use the future tense of the same verb (aller) instead of using the dedicated future tense of the significative verb. You could anyway hear or read both forms from native speakers.

Comment: merci pour votre perspicacité Laurent !

Comment: I will get better tomorrow =health, J'irai mieux demain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your sentences are correct, but they mean quite different things:

"*Je vais aller mieux*" means that you're going to recover from some illness.

"*Je deviendrai meilleur*" means that you will become a better man, either on a moral or a technical point of view.

Comment: Thanks BBBreiz. Can you explain why this is please?

Comment: "aller bien" is an expression used to say "I'm fine": In French , to say "How are you?"(Britain), or "How do you do?" (America), people say "Comment allez-vous?", the answer usually being "Je vais bien" ("I'm fine"). But when you have been ill, you can say "Je vais mieux", meaning the illness is going away. On the other hand, "meilleur" has a more emphatic sense, and refers to a value.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying BBBreiz

Comment: It would have been kind of you to vote my answer!

Comment: Sorry! This is done now.